# How to identify which constant in an enum an int code value belongs to

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, ios7, enums

**Update 1**

```
+(PKMainWeatherType)getWeatherTypeWithWeatherId:(NSUInteger)weatherId{

    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeAdditional) return PKMainWeatherTypeAdditional;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeExtreme) return PKMainWeatherTypeExtreme;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeClouds) return PKMainWeatherTypeClouds;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeAtmosphere) return PKMainWeatherTypeAtmosphere;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeSnow) return PKMainWeatherTypeSnow;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeRain) return PKMainWeatherTypeRain;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeDrizzle) return PKMainWeatherTypeDrizzle;
    if(weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeThunderstorm) return PKMainWeatherTypeThunderstorm;
    return PKMainWeatherTypeNone;
}
```

Is this the best way to get the appropriate constant?

---

**Original Post**

Given the following enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, PKMainWeatherType)
{
    PKMainWeatherTypeNotFound = 0,
    PKMainWeatherTypeThunderstorm = 200,
    PKMainWeatherTypeDrizzle = 300,
    PKMainWeatherTypeRain = 500,
    PKMainWeatherTypeSnow = 600,
    PKMainWeatherTypeAtmosphere = 700,
    PKMainWeatherTypeClouds = 800,
    PKMainWeatherTypeExtreme = 900,
    PKMainWeatherTypeAdditional = 951,
};
```

how can I identify which constant say code number `224` belongs to? In this case it would belong to `PKMainWeatherTypeThunderstorm`.

In this case, I want all numbers that fall within the range to be associated to their constant.
Have a look at [this link](http://www.openweathermap.org/weather-conditions) to see code values and their associations.

I was thinking of `flooring` the int code value but then that would create problems for the last constant since the last two constants share the same 900 domain and thus flooring would cause all code values above 951 to be categorised in the constant before which has a floored value of 900.

Can anyone provide a clean solution?

Comment: @Conclusio it's an enum.

Answer (score 0):

If `PKMainWeatherTypeAdditional` is the only one that doesn't follow the pattern you'd just need to handle that particular case and then calculate the rest.

Strictly given the codes available in the link provided:

```
+ (PKMainWeatherType)getWeatherTypeWithWeatherId:(NSUInteger)weatherId {

    if (weatherId >= PKMainWeatherTypeAdditional) return PKMainWeatherTypeAdditional;

    return (PKMainWeatherType)(weatherId / 100 * 100);
}
```